# Leveraging Computational Techniques for Real-Life Option Pricing Models and Transforming Research into Utilitarian Products for Society

Tags: option-pricing, financial-markets

As a student specializing in computational finance, my passion lies in exploring the practical applications of advanced computational techniques in option pricing models for real-world scenarios. I have developed specialized computational schemes, including finite difference, finite element, and Artificial Neural Network (ANN)-based approximations, which have been tailored to solve complex models such as regime switching and fractional Black-Scholes equations.

Beyond academic pursuits, my ultimate aspiration is to generate research outcomes that can be transformed into real products with high utility for society. I believe that by applying computational finance methodologies to address practical financial challenges, we can create innovative solutions that positively impact decision-making processes in various industries.

To achieve this goal, I seek insights on how to effectively bridge the gap between theoretical research and real-world implementation. I am eager to understand the practical aspects of converting research findings into tangible products that can be readily utilized by financial professionals, institutions, and governing authorities.

Moreover, I am enthusiastic about collaborating with computer science students to enrich my research and tap into their expertise to develop user-friendly interfaces or applications. By combining computational finance with cutting-edge technological solutions, we can create highly utilitarian products that empower individuals and organizations in the financial domain.

As I plan to apply for positions like an interdisciplinary research associate at an IT institute, where the focus is on real-world applicability, I am keen on gaining insights into successful examples of research-to-product transformations and how interdisciplinary collaboration has played a pivotal role in achieving this goal.

Thank you for your special insights and real-world case studies that highlight the process of transforming computational finance research into practical products with significant societal impact.